# ordering of figures in two-column environment

Tags: floats, two-column

I have several figures in my two-column environment, I am using the template of MNRAS:

https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/mnras

I have found that latex never respect the ordering of the figures. The problem is that there is a quite large figure that always ends up after three smaller figures. I have seen that there is a package called `afterpage`, but that shouldn't work in a two column environment.

What can I do to improve the ordering?

Comment: can you add a working example of this

Comment: The template you mention doesn't replicate the problem. Could you include a minimal document that replicates the problem *here*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in latex: add `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}` at the start of the document.

Comment: ok, now the ordering is correct, but the result is horrible. There are empty columns with no text, just nearby the single column figures. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @simona Not without a usable test example. Note that 2-column figures always go on to the next page at the earliest, unlike single column figures they can not float to the top of the current page, so sometimes you need to move the `figure*` earlier in the source file.

Comment: OK, I removed `afterpage` and moved the position of figures in the code, and that made it. I didn't know that two-column figures would not float to the top of the page.

Comment: @simona basically the problem is if the figure is encounted in the second column, the first column has already been saved in a full height box and the column break fixed, so there is no way to add a full column figure. (In the first column figure it would be possible but would complicate the code and latex has never attempted that)